# Finding Probabilities of Normally Distributed Random Variables

Tags: probability, distributions, random-variable

A random variable $x$ is known to follow a normal distribution with mean $35$ and standard deviation $7$ Find the following probabilities: a. $P(x<25)$ b. $P(x<33)$ c. $P(x>42)$ d. $P(x>35)$ e. $P(28<x<38)$

Comment: All may be found with reasonable accuracy by standardizing and using printed standard normal tables. Using R all may be found directly: (a,b)  code `pnorm(c(25,33), 35, 7)` returns $0.07656373,  0.38754848,$ (c,d) code `1 - pnorm(c(42,35), 35, 7)` returns
 $0.1586553, 0.5000000,$ (e) code `diff(pnorm(c(28,38), 35, 7))` returns $0.5072272.$ in R, `pnorm` is normal CDF with specified $\mu, \sigma.$

Comment: Standardizing (b): $P(X < 33) = P(Z < (33-35)/7 = - 2/7 = -0.2857) \approx 0.3859,$ where $Z$ is standard normal. Used table entry corresp to -0.29 to get answer above. By interpolating between results for $-0.28$ and $-0.29$ you could get a little closer to $0.3875.$ This is OK for a class in which you're expected to learn how to use printed table, but in practice, with statistical calculators or software, you get more accurate answers more easily. Maybe the current generation of stat/probability texts is the final one with printed tables.

Answer (score 1):

**Graphical comment:**

Figures for (a) and (b): Desired probability is the area under the
density curve to the *left* of the vertical dashed line. [The *total* area
under a density curve is $1.]$

```
par(mfrow=c(1,2))
curve(dnorm(x,35,7), 10, 60, lwd=2, ylab="PDF", main="NORM(35,7)")
 abline(h=0,col="green2"); abline(v = 25, col="red", lty="dashed")
curve(dnorm(x,35,7), 10, 60, lwd=2, ylab="PDF", main="NORM(35,7)")
 abline(h=0,col="green2"); abline(v = 33, col="red", lty="dashed")
par(mfrow=c(1,1))
```

[image]

Figures for (c) and (e): Desired probability for (c) is the area under the
density curve to the *right* of the vertical dashed line; for (e) the
area between the two vertical lines.

```
par(mfrow=c(1,2))
curve(dnorm(x,35,7), 10, 60, lwd=2, ylab="PDF", main="NORM(35,7)")
 abline(h=0,col="green2"); abline(v = 42, col="blue", lty="dashed")
curve(dnorm(x,35,7), 10, 60, lwd=2, ylab="PDF", main="NORM(35,7)")
 abline(h=0,col="green2"); abline(v = c(28,38), col="darkgreen", lty="dashed")
par(mfrow=c(1,1))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It is generally known that if $X \sim N(\mu, \sigma^2)$ for known $\mu$, $\sigma^2$, then $\frac{X - \mu}{\sigma} \sim N(0, 1)$. We can simply use this in doing your problem here. That is, we have that $Z = \frac{X - 35}{7} \sim N(0,1)$. Thus,

$$P(X < 25) = P\left(Z < \frac{25 - 37}{7}\right),$$
where this just amounts to looking at the normal distribution table. I will not do the rest of the problems because they are very similar.

For e), it is pretty straightforward once you notice that
$$P(28 < X < 38) = P(X < 38 ) - P(X < 28),$$
where since we are dealing with continuous R.V., the inequality versus strict inequality does not matter.